# Count & GroupBy Function Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, count, eloquent

I'm building some analytical stat graphs for an administrator dashboard using Laravel.  I'm having a lot of fun.  Though I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding how to utilize the SQL queries and GroupBy function to achieve some stuff.

End goal: retreive the **count** of **users** who were created and **groupBy** the week they registered.

So far I'm using this:

```
DB::table("users")
   ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count"))
   ->orderBy("created_at")
   ->groupBy(function ($query)
     {
       return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($query->created_at)->format("W");
     })
   ->get();
```

I'm getting an error in Tinker (which is where I do a majority of my testing at the moment it's something like this:

```
PHP warning:  strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string,  object given in 
/Users/Ian/sites/bangerz-army/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php on line 58
```

I had gotten a similar query to work in PHP but for performance reasons I'd prefer to keep as much of the math in SQL as possible.

/ Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DB::raw()` in your group by

```
DB::table("users")
   ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(*) as count, WEEK(created_at)"))
   ->orderBy(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'))
   ->groupBy(DB::raw('WEEK(created_at)'))
   ->get();
```

Comment: Or use `orderByRaw` and `groupByRaw` :)

Comment: This works perfectly as I store my created_at's as Carbon instances as per Laravel default.  I greatly appreciate the help!